# Can && be used in if statements?

Tags: java, android-studio, button

Im working on an app that converts a currency. I need it so that the user can enter an amount and then select one button which will have a specific material on it and then the user will click another button to convert it to another material. Eg copper converted into silver. But when I run the program for some reason when I click the calculate button nothing happens on the screen and no errors appear. Is it because I'm using && or something else I am very confused as to why it is not working. Here is my code:

```
    btCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            int convert = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

            if (btCopper1.isPressed() && btSilver2.isPressed()){
                btCalculate.setText(convert);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You can always use && in your if statement condition. It will execute the if statement if both side of the operand holds true.

Comment: When both of the correct buttons are pressed and the the calculate button is pressed the code still doesn't execute and I'm not sure why. Can you see the problem? I thought it might I've been from the && @Som

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to figure out what is going wrong in your code you can use print statements or the debugging option in your IDE to step through your code line by line to see where the problem occurs.

I added a couple print statements to your code to show whether btCopper1 and btSilver2 are pressed and another print statement showing that the btCalculate() method will be called. If nothing prints to the console window at all then you aren't even reaching the onClick() method and something else went wrong before the portion of code that you posted.

```
 btCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        
        System.out.println("btCopper1="+btCopper1.isPressed() + "  btSilver2="+btSilver2.isPressed());
        
        int convert = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
        if (btCopper1.isPressed() && btSilver2.isPressed()){
            
            System.out.println("btCalculate is called");

            btCalculate.setText(convert);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Tekkerue where do I see the print statements because I ran the app and don't see anything new?

Comment: I found this under run:

Comment: I/System.out: btCopper1=false  btSilver2=false
I/System.out: btCopper1=false  btSilver2=false
I/System.out: btCopper1=false  btSilver2=false

Comment: Yes, that is what you are looking for. The print statements show that none of your buttons return "true" when calling isPressed() on them, which is why your btCalculate method never gets called. What kind of buttons are you using? Do they retain their "pressed" state? In other words, if you press a button to turn it "ON" does isPressed() return true? And if you press the button again to turn it "OFF" does isPressed() return false? If not, then there maybe another method you can use to gets the button's on/off status. Or you can manage boolean variables yourself when you press a button.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` means and -- so both buttons have to be pressed at the same time for the `if` to evaluate to true? Not sure if this is what you intended to do.

Comment: I don't want them to be pressed at the exact same time per say I want one button to be pressed and then the other button then the user to select calculate if you understand that? Is there a different way to write that?

Comment: @TaylaB You will need more complex logic to do what you want. You should declare variables that keep track of when a button is pressed. Then you can use those variables in an `if` statement.

Comment: Maybe you can have variables `copper` and `silver` (for example), and when `btCopper1.isPressed()` you could set `copper` to true (and the same for silver). When the calculate button is pressed, check for `if (copper && silver)`

Comment: @Ycmelon would you assign copper and silver as boolean?

Comment: @TaylaB That was mainly psuedocode, I don't think variables for every material would be a good idea? But yes, you would assign them as booleans

Comment: So sorry @Ycmelon I'm new to this don't even know what psuedocode is.

Comment: @TaylaB Haha it's like "fake" code intended mostly for reading, anyway if you only have few materials it would probably be okay to assign some booleans.